# Why there is a confilict between what you see open a file and what input by ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
     array[i] = (char)('a'+i);
 }

    RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile("data1.txt", "rw");
    FileChannel fc = rf.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = null;
    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){            
        buffer.putInt((int) array[i]);              
    }    
    buffer.flip();
    fc.write(buffer);
```

Above code, I try to write 97,98...into the file and when I read it from a ByteBuffer and then print it to the screen it appears to be 97,98,...

but when I open the file it appears to a,b,c.....

why

Comment: You write **bytes** to a file but open the file in a **text** editor and expect to see the same thing? Or did I misunderstand your expectations?

Comment: Wait you don't use XTree Gold's hex viewer to read text files? I assumed everyone did :)

Comment: No, I am a beginner, so you mean if I write bytes into file, I could not open it with a text editor? My professor lets me use the bytebuffer, but that means I could not say open it and read it with my eyes? I must read it my computer? can I change its format to .txt

Comment: All files on all computers are just bits and bytes. When you open the file in a text editor, you're seeing the textual representation of the bytes.

Comment: 97 is the ASCII code for 'a'. 98 is the ASCII code for 'b'. But why do people initialize new variables to zero or `null` and then assign them in the very next line? Something I've never understood.